# Range-based loop from a temporary returned by a member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a little unsure how the new (as of c++11) ranged-based loop works internally.

If I were to do something like...

```
for( auto i : someclass.Elements() )
{
 ...
}
```

...where "Elements()" returns a a temporary, are there any side effects I might not be aware of?

I will add a working prototype at the bottom of this question.

I've verified that the type returned by "Elements()" is created once, which is my biggest concern. To be honest, this feels a bit *too* easy, and I haven't seen this implementation else where.

For context, I have an XML library I created and want to be able to iterate over an element's children ("for( auto child: element->Children() ) {...}"), it's attributes ("for( auto attribute : element->Attributes() ( {...}"), and perhaps more specific children ("for( auto cats : element->Children( "cats" ) ) {...}".

Here is a working prototype:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template< typename T >
class Array
{
public:
    Array()
    {       
    }

    Array( T firstValue )
    {
        m_elements.push_back( firstValue );
    }

    Array( const std::list< T > & values )
    {
        m_elements.insert( m_elements.begin(), values.begin(), values.end() );
    }   

    virtual ~Array() 
    {
    }

    void Add( T value )
    {
        m_elements.push_back( value );
    }

    const T & operator[]( int index ) const
    {
        return m_elements[ index ];
    }   

    size_t Count() const
    {
        return m_elements.size();
    }

    class ElementsIterable
    {
        Array & m_array;
    public:
        ElementsIterable( Array & array ) : m_array( array )
        {
            std::cout << "ElementsIterable Constructed" << std::endl;
        }

        class iterator
        {
        public:
            iterator( Array & array, size_t index )
                : m_array( array ), m_index( index )
            {
            }

            iterator & operator++()
            {
                m_index++;
                return *this;
            }

            bool operator!=( const iterator & itr ) const
            {
                return m_index != itr.m_index;
            }

            const T & operator*() const
            {
                return m_array[ m_index ];
            }

        private:
            Array & m_array;
            size_t m_index;
        };

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator( m_array, 0 );
        }
        iterator end() {
            return iterator( m_array, m_array.Count() );
        }
    };

    ElementsIterable Elements()
    {
        return ElementsIterable( *this );
    }

private:
    std::vector< T > m_elements;
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    Array< int > array( { 1, 2, 3 } );
    array.Add( 4 );

    for( auto a : array.Elements() )
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very strange data structure design for an `array`-like class (and you'd be better off just using a `std::vector` here anyway). When designing an STL style container and considering iteration one tends to stick to the standard's [`Iterator Concepts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator).

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is `ContentsInReverse` and how does it relate to this code?

Comment: @Barmar: Bugger! I think I mixed my simplified question with my actual use! Corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the following page for an exact description on what you can replace `for` by as a mental model:

[Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Not only does it work with a function returning temporary, it's also possible to optimize a bit sometimes by doing `for (auto&& i : someclass.Elements())`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into auto&&; I'm still wrapping my brain around R-value references. It just so happens I have that site up; I couldn't figure from the examples what was actually happening with the ElementsIterable temporary. I think their "range_expression" in the examples doesn't really connect in my mind for what will happen to this temporary.

Comment: Does `&&` work as a universal reference after the auto here?

Comment: @kfsone `auto&&` is the same as `T&&`.  They are both [forwarding refertences](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf)

Comment: @Copperpot: rule of thumb: unless your type or container is extremely buggy (in its move), you can always write `auto&&` in a range-based for-loop. It comes handy when you move out of your loop variable - like when you fill another container with the values (i.e. roll your own <algorithm>)